# UPDATE, SUM sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these SQL instructions:

```
 CREATE TABLE discipline (
       did INT PRIMARY KEY,
       code VARCHAR(127) UNIQUE,
       university VARCHAR(127),
       number_students INT
 ) ENGINE=INNODB; 

 CREATE TABLE precedence(
      type VARCHAR(127),
      basic INT,
      advanced INT,
      PRIMARY KEY (basic, advanced), 
      FOREIGN KEY (basic) REFERENCES discipline(did) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      FOREIGN KEY (advanced) REFERENCES discipline(did)
 )ENGINE=INNODB;

 INSERT INTO discipline VALUES (1,'BD','U1',30);
 INSERT INTO discipline VALUES (2,'IBD','U2',30);
 INSERT INTO discipline VALUES (3,'SIBD','U3',30);
 INSERT INTO precedence VALUES ('optional',1,2);
 INSERT INTO precedence VALUES ('mandatory',2,3);
 UPDATE discipline SET did=did+did WHERE did=2;
```

I don't understand why the result of the instruction `SELECT SUM (DISTINCT did)` is 6 and isn't 8 (1+4+3). The value `2` (did) with the update instruction shouldn't be `4`? Can you explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the expected result be **8** (1+3+4) instead of 10?

Comment: 1+2+3=6 before the update. 1+4+3=8 after the update. What is that 10 ur expecting?

Comment: should be 8, and its working for me at least in SQL SERVER

Comment: Works in MySQL 5 too http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4f40/5

Comment: What DB are you using? Did you COMMIT? Does your SELECT run in another session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The value 2 (did) with the update instruction shouldn't be 4?

**No, it is 4, and it should.**

Because the `UPDATE` statements in SQL, are **All-at-once** operations. Meaning that all the expressions that you have, in the same logical phase are evaluated as if at the same point in time. In your example:

```
UPDATE discipline 
SET did = did + did 
WHERE did=2;
```

the `did` will equal to `4` because the expression `did = did + did` is evaluated wit the value `did = 2` at the same time.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1b10/4)

This will make your table looks like:

```
| DID | CODE | UNIVERSITY | NUMBER_STUDENTS |
---------------------------------------------
|   1 |   BD |         U1 |              30 |
|   3 | SIBD |         U3 |              30 |
|   4 |  IBD |         U2 |              30 | <<<<<
```

---

> I don't understand why the result of the instruction SELECT SUM
>   (DISTINCT did) is 6 and isn't 9 (1+4+3).

The values of `Did` after update will be:

```
1
3
4
```

Therefore:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT did) 
FROM discipline
```

Will equal to `8`.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1b10/5)

---

In your updated example, you won't be able to `UPDATE did`, becuase of the foreign key constraint and you will got an exception:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_2_65e0c`.`precedence`, CONSTRAINT `precedence_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`advanced`) REFERENCES `discipline` (`did`))

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14345)

In this case, you will need to add the `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` to the other foreign key constraint:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (advanced) REFERENCES discipline(did)
```

Then the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE discipline
SET did=did + did
WHERE did=2;
```

will be the same as explained before, and

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT did) 
FROM discipline
```

Will equal to `8`.

[**SQL fiddle demo of the two table(working)**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82c86/3)

Comment: And with the table precedence the value will change? Thanks.

Comment: @user1966757 Sorry, What do you mean?

Comment: I have edited my post I am using a table named precedence and I haven't put it on my post. This will change the result?

Comment: @user1966757 With the new table `precedence` you [**will not be able**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14345) to `UPDATE` the column `did` because of the `foreign key ` constraint

Comment: So the result is 6? What is the restrition? Thanks.

Comment: @user1966757 With the new precedence table, the same you entered in your question, you won't be able to do the update, unless you add `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` to the other column `advanced`, then the update will be the same as I explained before and it will be 8 not 6. See my edit and try it, if any thing goes worng just ask. And sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The correct result should be 8 because after the updating, the three values are (1, 4, 3) so the sub value is 8.